# Command line Argument to be parsed as integer value

Tags: c++, string, char, command, integer

I have following code:

```
TCHAR *cmd_line = GetCommandLine();
TCHAR *token1;
token1 = strchr(cmd_line, L'+');
MessageBox(NULL,token1, _T("test"), NULL);
```

When i enter

```
WesOPC.exe +10 -regserver
```

in the command prompt , the message box is displayed with

```
"+10 -regserver".
```

Now, 
I need to take the 2 char after '+' sign (10) and store it in a integer variable (convert char to integer.

So, how can i achieve these:

1. store 2 char after '+' from TChar to a string or char array , whichever is appropriate
2. convert the char array or string into integer

/////////////////Updated Code////////////////////////////////

I have added the following lines to the above code to convert char to int

```
int i, value=0;
for ( i = 0; token1 [ i ] != '\0'; ++i )
{
  int digit = token1 [ i ] - '0';// get value of current digit character 
  value = 10 * value + digit;
}
```

But it is showing "Debug Assertion error".

Is token1[1] not a correct statement. I am saying this because when i try following line, it also showed debug error.

```
MessageBox(NULL, LPCSTR(token1[1]), _T("test"), NULL);
```

The solution is in

[Unhandled exception for character parsed from command line in Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769770/unhandled-exception-for-character-parsed-from-command-line-in-win32-api/21769847?noredirect=1#21769847)

Comment: There shouldn't be casting involved in calling `MessageBox`.

Comment: @user3048644 - Just to let you know, your code will fail to compile if you build your program using Unicode character set.

Comment: I have removed the casting in messagebox . and i have used multi -character byte set

Answer (score 1):

You  can use `strtol` for this.  For example

```
const char *str = "+10 frogs";
const char *endptr;

long n = strtol(str + 1, &endptr, 0);
// now you should have n == 10 && (endptr == " frogs").
```

It keeps parsing the number until it finds some character that isn't
part of a number.  `*endptr` will point to that char.  You can use that
to Keep parsing the string, or to detect errors (see the `strtol` documentation).

Comment: It does  not showed any error while building the program . But while running the program, it poped up a dialog box with "Debug Assertion Failed"

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure it's always two characters, you can use

```
int val = 10 * (token1[1] - '0') + (token1[2] - '0');
```

If it's not always two digits, use `_ttoi(const char*)` to obtain the value after extracting the right string from `token1`.