# Unhandled exception for character parsed from command line in Win32 API

Tags: c, winapi, char, command-line-arguments

I have to parse the command line argument and convert certain char into integer.

I have the following code:

```
TCHAR *token1;
token1 = strchr(cmd_line, L'+');
MessageBox(NULL, token1, _T("test"), NULL);

//char *str = "+10 frogs";
TCHAR *endptr =" ";

long n = strtol(token1 + 1, &endptr, 0);

if (!*endptr)
    MessageBox(NULL, "No error", _T("test"), NULL);
else 
    MessageBox(NULL, "error", _T("test"), NULL);
```

When the command "WesOPC.exe +10 -regserver" is sent in command prompt , the message box displays "+10 -regserver".

I need to store 10 as integer .So, i used strtol but messagebox with error is displayed.

When i tried to debug it , the error seen at line

```
long n = strtol(token1 + 1, &endptr, 0);
```

is

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0042d368 in WesOPC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001.
```

'n' was supposed to be 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an AV at memory address `0x00000001`.  You are adding 1 to `token1`.  That means `token1` is NULL, but your code is not checking for that condition.  In fact, your fist call to `MessageBox()` should be showing a blank string in that situation.

Another problem is that you are mixing `char*`, `wchar_t*` and `TCHAR*` together in the same code.  `token1` is using `TCHAR*`, `L'+'` is using `wchar_t`, and `strchr()` expects `char*` and `char`.  your code should not even compile as-is.  Stop mixing data types together and pick one type to handle everything.

Try this instead:

```
// where cmd_line is TCHAR*...
TCHAR *token1 = _tcschr(cmd_line, _T('+'));
if (token1)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, token1, TEXT("test"), NULL);

    //char *str = "+10 frogs";
    TCHAR *endptr = " ";

    ++token1;
    long n = _tcstol(token1, &endptr, 0);

    if ((n == 0) && (endptr == token1))
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("error"), TEXT("test"), NULL);
    else 
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("No error"), TEXT("test"), NULL);
}
else
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("param not found"), TEXT("test"), NULL);
```

Or, stop supporting Ansi and just go full Unicode on everything:

```
// where cmd_line is LPWSTR...
LPWSTR token1 = wcschr(cmd_line, L'+');
if (token1)
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL, token1, L"test", NULL);

    //char *str = "+10 frogs";
    LPWSTR *endptr = L" ";

    ++token1;
    long n = wcstol(token1, &endptr, 0);

    if ((n == 0) && (endptr == token1))
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"error", L"test", NULL);
    else 
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"No error", L"test", NULL);
}
else
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"param not found", L"test", NULL);
```